# How to make use of the conditional statement in where clause?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

Here is my below code

```
string CampusId = "1";
string ClassId = "1";
var Class = GetClassesselect();
var model = (from sr in db.StudentRequests
join c in db.Classes
on sr.ClassId equals c.ClassId
where 
(CampusId ==""?"0": CampusId)
&& (ClassId == "" ? "0" : ClassId)
orderby sr.CreatedOn descending
select new Studentvm
{   
PaymentMethod = sr.PaymentMethod,
CampusId = (int)ViewData["CampusId"],
ClassId = (int)ViewData["ClassId"],
Availableclass = Class,   
})
.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10);


public IList<SelectListItem> GetClassesselect()
{
    // This comes from database.       
    var Class = db.Classes
        .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ClassName, Value = x.ClassId.ToString() })
        .ToList();
    Class.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "--Please Select--", Value = "" });
    return Class;
}
```

Here I am trying to make where statement as conditional that if campusid is null then by default it does not count that where condition else where condition should be taken

Example like In sql we are doing  some thing as

```
Select *
from Registration where     
(ISNULL(@CampusId,'')='' OR (R.CampusId = @CampusId ))
AND  (ISNULL(@ClassId,'')='' OR (TC.ClassId =@ClassId))
```

**here in above sql if @CampusId is null then that statement will not be taken as granted in where condition**

**So I am trying to do same thing in above Linq code how can I do so?**

Answer (score 1):

Very straightforward: use your param only if it is not null, and ignore otherwise.

```
where
    CampusId == null || sr.CampusId == CampusId
    &&
    ClassId == null || sr.ClassId == ClassId
```

Assuming those are "sr" properties of course.

Comment: Can you also answer me that why my model is giving issue as "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." when I m trying to pass CampusId = (int)ViewData["CampusId"], ClassId = (int)ViewData["ClassId"], in my model

Comment: @Xtremcool because it tries to evaluate the bit `ViewData["CampusId"]`, and it cannot. Do `int campusId = (int)ViewData["CampusId"]; query = //linq query goes`

Comment: if int is working then why Availableclass = Class, is not working for me?

Comment: I know this should be as different question, but as it is urgent I am asking in same as question as stackover flow allow different qiestion to as in 90 min and this is quit urgent for me

Comment: ot is givng me issue as Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context. when I add Availableclass=Class in model

Answer (score 1):

This does not work with a ternary operator, because the query provider is not able to translate that to SQL.
But if I understand your logic correct, you want to select records where `@CampusId` is null OR `R.CampusId` equals `@CampusId`. So

```
where 
(CampusId == null || CampusId == sr.CampusId) &&
(ClassId == null || ClassId == sr.ClassId)
```

Comment: Can you also answer me that why my model is giving issue as "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." when I m trying to pass CampusId = (int)ViewData["CampusId"],
ClassId = (int)ViewData["ClassId"],   in my model

Comment: @Xtremcool yes, because the linq query provider tries to translate that into sql, and that obviously does not work. You cannot put everything that's possible in c# into a linq2ef query.

Comment: if int is working then why Availableclass = Class, is not working for me?

Comment: where and how u mean Availableclass==?Class

Comment: I know this should be as different question, but as it is urgent I am asking in same as question as stackover flow allow different qiestion to as in 90 min and this is quit urgent for me

Comment: ot is givng me issue as Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context. when I add Availableclass=Class in model

Comment: @Xtremcool I'm afraid you have to ask a new question. I don't even know what your `AvailableClass` is. Seems it's not a string or int or whatever but some `SelectListItem`....this is not answerable in comments.

Comment: I my asked question I had define Availableclass=Class in model statement and it is giving me error. Check var Class = GetClassesselect();

Comment: @Xtremcool it's always the same reason: this assignment **cannot be translated into sql**